# c# Regex substring after second time char appear

Tags: c#, .net, regex

My problem is that I have a string in format like that:

```
dsadadsadas
dasdasda
dasda
4TOT651.43|0.00|651.43|98933|607.75|0.00|607.75|607.75|7621|14|0|0|799.42
dsda
dasad
das
```

I need to find the line that contains the **4TOT** and substring the value between the **socond** and **third** '|' any ideas how I can obtain that in regex substring?
For now I Have only that:

```
 var test = Regex.Match(fileContent, "4TOT.*").Value;
```

Which finds me entire line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this regex?
Seems to be working for me.

```
4TOT.*?\|.*?\|(.*?)\|
```

Captures the value you're looking for into a group.

Comment: Hmm I think that's the solution I was looking for, but I see that performance of Regex.Match(fileContent,"4TOT.*").Value.Split('|')[2]; is a bit better surprisingly then var test3 = Regex.Match(fileContent, @"4TOT.*?\|.*?\|(.*?)\|").Groups[1].Value;

Comment: I don't think it is "surprisingly", regular expressions can be kinda costy ;)

Comment: but on the other hand Regex.Match(fileContent,"4TOT.*").Value.Split('|')[2] is why faster then 
string line = input
    .Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Where(s => s.StartsWith("4TOT"))
    .FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Could you explain that second part of regex? I don't quite get that \? condition :D

Comment: The questionmark means non-greedy, http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: Ok I get the '?' now but why do we need to add the '\' before '|' thanks

Comment: | is a operator, so you need to escape it with \

Answer (score 3):

When the input is simple and follows a strict format like this, I usually prefer to use plain old string handling over regex. In this case it's spiced up with some LINQ for simpler code:

```
// filter out lines to use
var linesToUse = input
    .Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Where(s => s.StartsWith("4TOT"));

foreach (string line in linesToUse)
{
    // pick out the value
    string valueToUse = line.Split('|')[2];

    // more code here, I guess
}
```

If you know that the input contains only one line that you are interested in, you can remove the loop:

```
string line = input
    .Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Where(s => s.StartsWith("4TOT"))
    .FirstOrDefault();

string value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) ? string.Empty : line.Split('|')[2];
```

**Update**

Here is an approach that will work well when loading the input from a file instead:

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(@"c:\temp\input.txt")
                         .Where(s => s.StartsWith("4TOT")))
{
    string value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) ? string.Empty : line.Split('|')[2];
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

[`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) is new in .NET 4 and enumerates the lines in the file without loading the full file into memory, but instead it reads it line by line. If you are using an earlier version of .NET you can fairly easily make your own method providing this behavior.

Comment: I can't split the input coz the file is about 200MB, which i didn't mentioned eriler. I thought I could do it in one regex but I think it can't be done like that. Nevertheless I did use part of your code like that  
var test2 = Regex.Match(fileContent, "4TOT.*").Value.Split('|')[2];

Comment: Unfortunately I have to open entire file to cut it thousands of small bills and extract that value from every small document, and save it later. Anyway the idea with split on regex seems to give the best performance of all ;)

Comment: Anyway thanks Fredrik for the help, combining my and your code gives the best speed :D I did mark bassfriend answer as the right one coz I asked about the regex way to do it, so his answer was the best match :D

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you split your string twice: firstly with newline and then if target substring is found by `'|'` symbol without using of regex?

```
var tot = source.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray())
    .FirstOrDefault(s => s.StartsWith("4TOT"));

if (tot != null)
{
    // gets 651.43
    var result = tot.Split('|')
        .Skip(2)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex : `^4TOT(?:(?:[0-9]*(?:.[0-9]*)?)\|){2}([0-9]*(?:.[0-9]*)?).*`

This regex will match `4TOT` at the beginning followed by "2 numbers (decimal separated) then |" two times, and captures a number. The rest is ignored.

If you then use :

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
```

You will find the anwser into `match.Groups`

Memo:
Numbers are `[0-9]*\.[0-9]*`
Using the `(?: ... )` makes a non-capturing parenthesis